# store pointer in a vector

Tags: c, pointers, vector

I'm trying to store pointers in a vector, but show me a warning message: 
`p.c: In function ‘main’:`
`p.c:22:6: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]`
 `V[0] = number;`

I see what message means, but i couldn't fix the error.
I'm not sure if the vector declaration or struct is wrong(or both)!

Thanks for any help!

Just a example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void show(int *V[]);

struct age{
    int age;
    struct age *next;
};    
typedef struct age Age;

int main(){    
  int *V[3]; // Vector with 3 positions to store pointers

  Age* number = (Age *) malloc(sizeof(Age));
  number->age = 20; 
  number->next = NULL;

  V[0] = number;

  show(V);

  return 0;
}

void show(int *V[])
{
  printf ("\n%p\n",V[0]);
}
```

Comment: You can't store variable of type Age into array of type integer. Just set the array as Age *V[3] .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is that the V array is an array of int as it should be an array of Age.

You should instanciate it like that:

```
Age *V[3];
```

I hope it'll help :)

(if you just want an array of generic pointers, use `void*` but I would not be appropriate for this problem)

Comment: Yes Alex, you are correct!
Thanks, I wasn't looking the type of array!